# ¿Se puede usar Stack Overflow como blog técnico?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-propia

Me encuentro hoy con esta pregunta [LogIn UWP C# + MySQL + PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64014/15301) en la que el OP expone que ha estado investigando sobre un asunto y a continuación responde con una solución fruto de esa investigación.

¿Este tipo de preguntas deben considerarse on topic? En mi opinión no deben tener cabida, ya que si nos fijamos realmente no existe una pregunta. En este caso puede ser de utilidad a otros, pero podríamos encontrarnos con casos en los que el tema tratado solo fuese de utilidad para la persona que pregunta y contesta, convirtiendo el sitio en una especie de blog donde los usuarios "almacenasen" información para poder encontrarla luego mas fácilmente.

Comment: Nótese que en el centro de ayuda hay un artículo llamado [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](/help/self-answer), por lo que la práctica de preguntar y contestarse a uno mismo no es que no sea mala, sino que incluso se recomienda. Ahora bien, comparto tu punto de vista en cuanto a que la pregunta realmente no pregunta nada. Le he dejado un comentario, a ver qué hace.

Comment: Por supuesto @fedorqui, aqui no es una cuestión de preguntar algo, y tras una investigación llegar a una solución y responder tu propia pregunta. Este caso es diferente a mi parecer. Aqui el OP directamente ha venido a añadir la respuesta a una pregunta que nadie había planteado, por lo que a mi parecer tendría mas cabida en un blog personal que aqui.

Comment: Pero insisto, preguntar y responder a la vez no está mal de por sí. A mí me pasa a veces que tengo una duda, investigo un rato y finalmente encuentro una solución. Para que alguien pueda utilizar ese conocimiento, luego vengo aquí y [publico pregunta-respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/58487/83).

Comment: @fedorqui esa es la clave de mi pregunta. Tu tienes una duda y tras investigar consigues encontrar una solución. Por que añadirla aqui? Nadie te va a responder si ya has conseguido solucionarlo, por lo que no le veo el sentido aqui, si no tal vez en sitios como [Codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com). Otra cosa diferente, que me parece perfectamente válida, es realizar una pregunta, continuar investigando y finalmente dar con una solución. En ese caso si tiene sentido responder ya que la pregunta ya estaba planteada y es posible que incluso tenga ya comentarios o respuestas.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto pero no lo comparto. El enlace que pasé inicialmente ya se comenta: _Si tienes una pregunta la cual ya conoces su respuesta, y quisieras mantener un registro público de ese conocimiento de tal manera que otros (incluyéndote a ti mismo) puedan encontrarlo luego, es perfectamente aceptable hacer una pregunta y responderla tú mismo en los sitios de Stack Exchange_. Básicamente, la idea es que la duda que tú tuviste es probable que alguien la tenga en el futuro, por lo que compartiendo tu conocimiento otros se beneficiarán de él. Y claro, si es demasiado específica, se cierra.

Comment: @fedorqui tienes razón, ese enlace responde exactamente a mi pregunta. Yo no estoy de acuerdo, pero es evidente que según eso es perfectamente on topic hacerlo.

Comment: Y agrego, además de lo que comentó fedorqui, muchas veces eso permite que otros agreguen otras soluciones, lo cual enriquecería aún más al contenido.

Comment: Aunque no considero que mi pregunta sea un duplicado exacto ya que yo quería establecer un matiz, acepto el duplicado ya que el enlace propuesto por @fedorqui si que resuelve mi pregunta.

Comment: @Pikoh sí, entiendo que son dos preguntas distintas, pero con la misma respuesta (no se puede marcar como duplicado de la ayuda, pero creo que esa respuesta es la que mejor lo expresa, y tiene el enlace al final)

Comment: Perfectamente @Mariano. Ya te digo que acepto perfectamente el duplicado :)

Comment: Vaya no pensé que el mundo ardería por una publicación que hice, solo pretendía ayudar, espero que sus consejos para iluminarme, gracias. ;)

Comment: @Jorny jaja. El único problema que hay es que la respuesta no explica nada (solo código) y esta desaconsejado. Considera que para alguien que nunca uso esa tecnología puede no servir de nada. Por otro lado, este tipo de post (auto-respuesta) están bien vistos y se alienta a compartir información. Por algo existe la posibilidad de hacer la publicación conjunta de pregunta y respuesta todo en el mismo acto.  Salu2

Comment: @EmanuelVe tomaré en cuenta tu comentario, añadiré alguna información a la respuesta. ;)